# Taking a survey not more than once on Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

How can I make sure than participants who are taking the survey designed by me not allowed to take the survey more than once on Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a HIT, a given worker can only take that HIT once. If you have, e.g., multiple HITs that are all the same study (either different conditions you launch simultaneously or multiple HITs that you post over time), then workers will have access to each version. Of course, someone might have multiple accounts or something (but that is rare and against Terms of Use). So, as long as you only have one HIT (with however many assignments you need - one assignment being one worker), then you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that posting a HIT once means a Turker can only take it once, many people find that some participants malingered, satisficed, etc. and have to resubmit their HITs a second or third time. Requsters also sometimes realize they need more responses, and therefore post their HITs again. In these situations your solution is the DoesNotExist qualifier: http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2014/07/new-qualification-comparators-add-greater-flexibility-to-qualifications-.html

Comment: Why would you post a HIT again? Adding assignments to an existing HIT avoids that problem entirely.

Comment: You realize you need to pay more, or less, or you want to change or remove qualifications. It happens quite frequently with survey Requesters.

Comment: That can all be achieved with modifications to an existing HIT via the API.

Comment: Yup, but for those using the GUI it can't. There are also researchers who post their HIT at varying times on varying days to ensure their population is representative, and they won't want retakes.